# Referring top user profiles in a discussion

Tags: support, stack-overflow, users

With reference to gamification implementations on the internet, I plan to include SO as an example in a competition within the firm I work. I plan to quote examples of users registered in the site by taking a couple of examples from the Users listing of SO. Though the information is publicly available, can anybody guide me if there is a permission thats required, and how to go about getting it OR will a reference to the website be good enough?

Comment: What exactly you are going to do with the information? Anyhow, as long as you clearly state the source can't see any problem.

Comment: A couple of user profiles will be taken as examples to demonstrate the diversity and quality of active users of the SO community. This information will just be a part of a powerpoint presentation slide. This is purely internal and does not include any commercial angle and the target audience are a very small population of the firm.

Comment: Can't see any problem with that then. No time for detailed answer, most likely someone else will post such answer soon though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see no problem with that, and no specific permission is required.

All user contributions posted on Stack Overflow are licensed under the [CC:Wiki license](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/), which requires you to attribute the work (a link to the source is enough, or, in a PowerPoint slide, just state it's taken from Stack Overflow).

Highlighting specific users with profile information still only uses user contributions to the site, so this all falls under the same license.